# selenium - How to enter value into box?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to change the "Adults" value on the [Southwest Airlines website](https://www.southwest.com/) using Selenium (Python). I want to be able to specify the number of passengers directly, instead of hitting the +/- buttons. Seems like it should be fairly easy to do, but I can't figure it out. Here is the code I have (not working):

```
passengers = browser.find_element_by_id('air-pax-count-adults')
passengers.send_keys('3') # Number of passengers
```

I've also tried the following (doesn't work either):

```
passengers = browser.find_element_by_id('air-pax-count-adults')
passenges.click()
passengers.send_keys('3') # Number of passengers
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "readonly" input and you have to *remove the `readonly` attribute* in order to be able to interact with it in a traditional way:

```
passengers = browser.find_element_by_id('air-pax-count-adults')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly', 0);", passengers)

passengers.click()
passengers.clear()
passengers.send_keys('3')  # Number of passengers
```